# HTML CSS trying to make fixed sidenavbar responsive

Tags: css

I made HTML page, with left side navbar(vertical), position fixed , so it will not move when i scroll down the other div(the guide with text),
after that div with text.
I am trying to make it responsive, but since it is fixed position it won't help.
Is there any trick to fix this?
example (not extacly as mine, since its very long code above 200 lines with css and everything)
but still it is the same idea.
notice because the navbar is fixed position it will hide the guide div when screen pixels go down

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 260px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 140px;
  left: 135px;
  background: #eee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #2b8bc6;
  display: block;
}
.sidenav h3 {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}


.box22 {
    background-color: #fff;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="sidenav">

      <a href="#clients">HTML 1 editors</a>
      <a href="#clients">HTML 2 editors</a>
      <a href="#contact">HTML 3 editors</a>

    </div>

 <div class="box22">

          <h1>HTML part 1 intro</h1>
        <p>text</p>
     </div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relative CSS Unit like `vw`, which is equivalent to 1% of the total viewport.

Right now, you've got it set to an absolute size, `260px`. Change that to something like `10vw`.

For more info on CSS units, including a list of relative units, check out this [W3 page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

---

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 10vw;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 140px;
  left: -6px;
  background: #eee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #2b8bc6;
  display: block;
}
.sidenav h3 {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}


.box22 {
    background-color: #fff;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 11vw;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="sidenav">

      <a href="#clients">HTML 1 editors</a>
      <a href="#clients">HTML 2 editors</a>
      <a href="#contact">HTML 3 editors</a>

    </div>

 <div class="box22">

          <h1>HTML part 1 intro</h1>
        <p>text</p>
     </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something with a bit of jQuery and more traditional nav layout for smaller responsive designs? Here's an idea: (fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/moqb29cr/)

HTML:

HTML 1 editors
      HTML 2 editors
      HTML 3 editors

```
      <h1>HTML part 1 intro</h1>
<div id="responsive_nav">
        &#x2630;
      </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu maximus turpis. Cras non leo et felis consectetur tristique. Fusce rutrum erat non facilisis suscipit. Quisque id mi dictum, vestibulum massa sit amet, pharetra justo. Sed rutrum, ligula iaculis mattis sagittis, nisi urna commodo diam, eu auctor mi nunc eu odio. Quisque vel odio viverra, imperdiet augue at, rhoncus orci. Nullam fringilla id tortor vel rutrum. Morbi interdum egestas luctus. Suspendisse nec lacus lacinia, mollis massa auctor, consectetur nisi. Quisque interdum iaculis turpis vitae posuere. Aenean sollicitudin blandit interdum. Nulla vel bibendum nibh, at semper ex.Sed ornare dolor dui, sit amet efficitur lacus varius eget. Nunc ut urna at risus tristique cursus. Nulla rutrum rhoncus odio, vel volutpat nibh hendrerit sed. Nulla tempus id erat nec dictum. Phasellus laoreet pretium posuere. Etiam fringilla ipsum ut porttitor euismod. Mauris auctor nisi vitae sapien lacinia, porta tempor est consequat. Phasellus auctor bibendum varius. Duis convallis justo vitae nibh finibus, et vestibulum enim congue. Sed id nulla quam. Quisque sed cursus eros. Integer ut telVestibulum malesuada elementum diam non tincidunt. Integer et pharetra mi, nec tempus erat. Integer tempor dictum feugiat. Duis vel elit tellus. Etiam ornare consequat accumsan. Fusce sit amet sapien vitae mauris vestibulum mattis a sit amet odio. Maecenas volutpat orci tincidunt ante suscipit eleifend. Sed tempor faucibus ligula, vitae vulputate tortor viverra id. Phasellus ultricies, erat et fermentum tincidunt, augue nisl cursus nulla, id facilisis nunc ante commodo quam.Praesent euismod varius eros non euismod. Fusce posuere nisl lacus, a condimentum nunc efficitur eu. Ut et molestie tortor. Nunc vitae magna at felis rutrum blandit vel ut est. Aenean condimentum ipsum nec lorem condimentum convallis. Donec nec diam vel enim dapibus pretium eu at tortor. Maecenas vulputate sed diam ac aliquam. Aenean pharetra ullamcorper nisi, at egestas justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.Morbi malesuada dui vitae ex pretium, eget congue nisi viverra. Donec hendrerit lorem non augue aliquet dictum. Vivamus molestie in justo in pharetra. Nunc finibus, velit sit amet malesuada bibendum, turpis elit maximus tortor, et vehicula ex tellus non lectus. Donec rhoncus erat placerat, pulvinar est eu, tincidunt neque. Donec ligula enim, bibendum non est non, porta blandit risus. In et facilisis lorem, ut commodo ipsum. Nulla feugiat felis vel rhoncus ultrices. Vivamus vitae orci tincidunt, mattis risus a, mattis dui. Curabitur congue enim at lorem lobortis, nec venenatis leo interdum. Quisque id euismod felis, ut congue nunc.</p>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#responsive_nav").click(function(){
    $(".sidenav").toggle();
});
```

And CSS:

```
    p {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:75%;
  left:28%;

}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 85px;
  left;0px;
  background: #eee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #2b8bc6;
  display: block;
}
.sidenav h3 {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}


.box22 {
    background-color: #fff;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
#responsive_nav {
    display:none;
  }
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .sidenav {
    display:none;
    }
  #responsive_nav {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    top:15px;
    left:80%;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:thin solid #ccc;
    padding:10px;
  }
  #responsive_nav:hover {
    background-color:#ccc;
    border-radius:6px;
    padding:10px;
  }
  p {
    width:90%;
    left:0%;
  }
  }
```

Comment: You can do it with just javascript as well...I like jQuery but is not necessary. All you need to do is just toggle the mobile nav.

Comment: i have too much work to learn this, i just used vn instd of px, now the navbar only hide the text in very small screens , and i used media quarry to get rid of him and use arrow instd. so that good for now! thanks